# Vapor 4 - Unable to build hello world on fresh install

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu-20.04, vapor

I've used Vapor 3, but this is my first time with version 4. I'm setting up a fresh server environment with Ubuntu 20.04 and Swift 5.6.1. I can create a new Swift project, build, and run it just fine without issue.

Next I follow along with Vapor's [Install](https://docs.vapor.codes/install/linux/) and [Getting Started](https://docs.vapor.codes/getting-started/hello-world/) docs. I'm able to install Vapor Toolbox just fine. Then to test I work along with the docs and run:

```bash
vapor new hello -n
cd hello
swift run
```

At first it seems to be working fine, grabbing dependencies:

```bash
....
Creating working copy for https://github.com/vapor/async-kit.git
Working copy of https://github.com/vapor/async-kit.git resolved at 1.12.0
Creating working copy for https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-extras.git
Working copy of https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-extras.git resolved at 1.12.0
Building for debugging...
[1605/1613] Wrapping AST for Backtrace for debugging
```

At that point it exits without an error message or anything.

If I run again it's similar situation. Eventually it spits out an error:

```bash
error: emit-module command failed due to signal 9 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Running verbose spits out a huge and unreadable string of paths and commands.

EDIT: [Here's a paste](https://pastebin.com/Re4Yer6J) of the verbose output since it's too long to include

Comment: Need to see the log.

Comment: @cora Edited with paste of verbose output.

Comment: Run ‘swift build -c release’ and see if you get different behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're running out of memory. Try enabling swap or giving the machine more RAM and try again

Comment: Yup, memory was the issue. Don't know why that didn't occur to me. Thanks.